# Opengl tessellation error on mac

Tags: macos, opengl, glsl, shader, tessellation

I'm trying tessellation shader on mac but it returns a list of errors:

```
ERROR: 0:2: Invalid use of layout 'vertices'
ERROR: 0:12: Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_InvocationID'
ERROR: 0:12: Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_InvocationID'
ERROR: 0:13: Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_InvocationID'
ERROR: 0:14: Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_TessLevelInner'
ERROR: 0:15: Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_TessLevelOuter'
ERROR: 0:16: Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_TessLevelOuter'
ERROR: 0:17: Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_TessLevelOuter'
```

This seems there is something wrong with tessellation controller shader.

```
#version 410
layout(vertices = 3) out;
in vec3 vPosition[];
out vec3 tcPosition[];
uniform float TessLevelInner;
uniform float TessLevelOuter;

#define ID gl_InvocationID

void main()
{
    tcPosition[ID] = vPosition[ID];
    if (ID == 0) {
        gl_TessLevelInner[0] = TessLevelInner;
        gl_TessLevelOuter[0] = TessLevelOuter;
        gl_TessLevelOuter[1] = TessLevelOuter;
        gl_TessLevelOuter[2] = TessLevelOuter;
    }
}
```

My opengl projects works fine on my 2010 Windows pc...
I'm wondering if this is a macosx issue? The GPU on my mac is Intel Iris.
Anyone got a clue for this...

The main.cpp code is shared [here](https://codeshare.io/5zlmyN)

```
static GLuint LoadProgram( const char* vert, const char* tcs, const char* tes,const char* geom, const char* frag )
{
    GLuint prog = glCreateProgram();
    if( vert ) AttachShader( prog, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vert );
    if( tcs ) AttachShader( prog, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, tcs );
    if( tes ) AttachShader( prog, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, tes );
    if( geom ) AttachShader( prog, GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER, geom );
    if( frag ) AttachShader( prog, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, frag );
    glLinkProgram( prog );
    CheckStatus( prog );
    return prog;
}
```

Comment: Are you requesting a *Core* OpenGL context during initialization?

Comment: I initialized GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE in glfw  initialization by :glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE );

Comment: please check the main.cpp I shared above

Comment: Please add all the code relevant to the question to the question itself. Off-site links could die and the question would get useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `LoadProgram` you call `AttachShader`  with `GL_VERTEX_SHADER` as type for the both `tcs` and `tes`.

But a *VertexShader* does not have those identifiers the shader compiler complains about.

You have to use the correct shader types (`GL_TESS_CONTROL_SHADER` and `GL_TESS_EVALUATION_SHADER`) for your tesselation shaders.